# GUI for find which can show video thumbnails

Tags: find, software-rec, gui

Is there a GUI for `find` (or just a graphical search tool which supports regex searches on filenames starting from a specific directory) which is able to show thumbnails found video and image files?

I don't want something which uses an index like `recoll`, `tracker` or something like that in this case.